# Meaning of "thank you for nothing"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning or nuance of "thank you for nothing" as a reply to another's choice?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question should really say why. +1 from me since it's a reasonable question.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I was not the downvoter, but you could improve the question by indicating what research you have attempted, and why the literal parsing of *thank you for nothing* does not make sense to you, *and* the context where you encountered the expression. It is more commonly formulated as *[thanks for nothing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/thanks-for-nothing)*. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may interest you.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase "thank you for nothing" is a dismissive and contemptuous way of telling somebody that they were no help at all.  Generally, you thank somebody for *something* they've done.  A thank you for *nothing* is as empty of gratitude as the speaker thinks the offer of help is of no use.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the definition of the ironic idiom *thanks for nothing* according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanks_for_nothing):

> Expression of displeasure towards a person who has not provided what was wanted.

Example:

> Person A: "I brought another pencil for you, but I accidentally broke it."
>
> Person B: "*Thanks for nothing*; now I'll have to find yet another one."